# Verilog Pipelined Multiplier Intuition

Tags: system-verilog

I'm trying to understanding how the following code works, but struggling to put it together in my head. Could someone give me a more intuitive (visual) explanation of how this pipelined multiplier stage works?

```
// This is one stage of an 8 stage (9 depending on how you look at it)
// pipelined multiplier that multiplies 2 64-bit integers and returns
// the low 64 bits of the result.  This is not an ideal multiplier but
// is sufficient to allow a faster clock period than straight *
module mult_stage(
                    input clock, reset, start,
                    input [63:0] product_in, mplier_in, mcand_in,

                    output logic done,
                    output logic [63:0] product_out, mplier_out, mcand_out
                );



    logic [63:0] prod_in_reg, partial_prod_reg;
    logic [63:0] partial_product, next_mplier, next_mcand;

    assign product_out = prod_in_reg + partial_prod_reg;

    assign partial_product = mplier_in[7:0] * mcand_in;

    assign next_mplier = {8'b0,mplier_in[63:8]};
    assign next_mcand = {mcand_in[55:0],8'b0};

    //synopsys sync_set_reset "reset"
    always_ff @(posedge clock) begin
        prod_in_reg      <= #1 product_in;
        partial_prod_reg <= #1 partial_product;
        mplier_out       <= #1 next_mplier;
        mcand_out        <= #1 next_mcand;
    end

    // synopsys sync_set_reset "reset"
    always_ff @(posedge clock) begin
        if(reset)
            done <= #1 1'b0;
        else
            done <= #1 start;
    end

endmodule
```

Comment: which part of this code is the problem for you? remember it is a single stage which gets instantiated 8 times to get the full result and produces just a partial multiplication result.

Comment: So I understand how the stages form a pipeline, but I don't understand how this produces the correct result. When we shift the mcand to the left by 8 bits, we make the least 8 significant bits in the partial product zero, which is what I would expect, but we also lose the 8 most significant bits of the mcand. In paper and pencil multiplication we normally keep all the bits of the mcand and simply add 8 zeros to the end.

Comment: why do you think that this code is correct? Also, you need to know how the stages are connected at the upper level. And there are other questionable things like #1 in the code.

Comment: @Serge My current understanding is this: In this code, we are essentially shifting the multiplicand to the left to make the _n_ least significant bits of the partial product zero in the _n_th stage, just like you would when performing the addition by hand. The multiplier is shifted right in each stage to ensure the correct bits are used in each stage to determine a partial product. Since we are limited to a 64 bit product, we don't care about the bits we shift out of the multiplicand, since they are "overflow" when we add the partial products of the stages together.

Comment: I tried it on a paper and it does not work, unless the shift of mcand is ignored by the other stages. You need to verify that the model you provided works by simulation.  did you?

Comment: @Serge yes, it worked in simulation. If by ignore the shift of mcand, you mean the other stages are identical to this one, then yes that is the case